# from selenium import webbrowser ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Tags: python, selenium

Библиотека уже установлена(Requirement already satisfied), однако при запуске кода выдает ошибку, что библиотеки нет. При попытке повторной установки, пишет тоже самое(Requirement already satisfied)

Comment: Какую версию Python вы используете? Возможно у вас установлена 2 и 3 версии

Answer (score 0):

Для PyCharm:

File -> Setting -> Project: (название вашего проекта) -> Python Interpreter -> нажимаем на любую библиотеку ->  в посиковой строке ищем "selenium" кликаем -> Install packages